# Assertion Failure! VM not found in DRA cache

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, failover, infrastructure

Here I'm trying to migrate AWS VMs on to Azure. So I have created a process server inside AWS and I tried to add that VM to a protection group in Azure. While doing so I got stuck up with an error. So can any on from the other end please look into this and help me out....

[image]

**Error Details :**

Job ID: b83a20bd-5938-4cd1-9d58-159e228ab2f5-2016-04-04 15:07:48Z ActivityId: a165c292-856e-4855-8541-076ee321c7d2
Start Time: 4/4/2016 11:08:11 AM
Duration: 1 MINUTE

The requested operation did not complete. (Error code: 78007)
Provider error: Assertion Failure!
VM not found in DRA cache.

(Provider error code: 2)
Possible causes: Check the provider error for more details.
Recommendation: Resolve the issue as recommended in the provider error details.

UTC Time: Mon Apr 04 2016 15:33:53 GMT-0400 (Eastern Summer Time)
Browser: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36
Language: en-us
Portal Version: 5.16.00298.15 (rd_auxportal_stable.160325-0915)
PageRequestId: 759705df-186b-4302-976d-732007bce6b5
Email Address: praveengogula20@outlook.com (MSA)
Subscriptions: b33ed2cd-f0c2-44b1-bc17-dcb895d88385

Comment: Error : Job ID: dc71adac-7a0a-4427-ac96-d05af61674e7-2016-04-04 18:17:58Z ActivityId: 1d91f260-41c7-4090-b095-07dfd82b1e92
Start Time: 4/4/2016 2:18:21 PM
Duration: 1 MINUTE

The requested operation did not complete. (Error code: 78007)
Provider error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: (Provider error code: 2)
Possible causes: Check the provider error for more details.
Recommendation: Resolve the issue as recommended in the provider error details.

UTC Time: Mon Apr 04 2016 18:24:47 GMT-0400 (Eastern Summer Time)
Browser: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36
Language: en-us
Portal Version: 5.16.00298.15 (rd_auxportal_stable.160325-0915)
PageRequestId: 22c475cf-dc73-4c80-b946-e6769adbf821
Email Address: praveengogula20@outlook.com (MSA)
Subscriptions: b33ed2cd-f0c2-44b1-bc17-dcb895d88385

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Install the Mobility service manually on the Source Machine**

The software packages used to install the Mobility service are on the process server in C:\pushinstallsvc\repository. Log onto the process server and copy the appropriate installation package to the source machine based on the table below:-

for more details follow this below link :
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/site-recovery-vmware-to-azure-classic-legacy/

continue from step7 and do a manual installation of mobility service on the Source machine after creating a protection group.....